# Python regexp to capture numbers and dashes separated by spaces and comma

Tags: python, regex, string

I need to capture tokens such as `11`, `12-` `-13` and `14-15`

I wish to reject any strings that contain invalid tokens that are not specified above such as `12--` and `4-5-6`
These can be separated by any number of spaces which may or may not include a single coma.  So for the string:

`43,5  67- -66,53-53   ,  6`

I wish to return

```
('43', '5', '67-', '-66', '53-53', '6')
```

This is what I have tried:

```
import re

num = r'\d{1,4}'
token = r'(?:-%s)|(?:%s-%s)|(?:%s-)|(?:%s)' % (num, num, num, num, num)
sep = r'\s*,?\s*'
valid = r'(%s)(?:%s(%s))*' % (token, sep, token)

test = re.compile(valid)
m = test.match("43,5 67-  -66,53-53 , 6")
print(m.groups())
```

but it prints only the first and last numbers:

```
('43', '6')
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`re.findall`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall):

```
>>> re.findall(r'[-\d]+', '43,5 67- -66,53-53 , 6')
['43', '5', '67-', '-66', '53-53', '6']
```

---

**UPDATE**

Use negative lookaround assertions to exclude invalid matches.

```
>>> pattern = r'(?<![-\d])(\d+-\d+|-\d+|\d+-|\d+)(?![-\d])'
>>> re.findall(pattern, '43,5 67- -66,53-53 , 1--, 2, --3, -4-')
['43', '5', '67-', '-66', '53-53', '2']
```

Comment: that was quick and answers the question, I am impressed! However, I also want to reject invalid input such as --7 and 9--6.  I will update my question to reflect this.

Comment: @HolyMackerel, How about `-6-` ?

Comment: that would be not valid so I would want to return nothing / no match.  I have updated the question.  Only one or zero `-`s is allowed in a valid token.

Comment: Regex guru, I bow down to you. Throw me a complicated OOP structure and I'll unravel it easily. Give me a network to plot, no problem. Make me write a regex expression and I'll curl up into the fetal position and cry. I salute you.

Comment: Thank you, that's better but it fails for `1-3-5` which I would want to reject.  It returns `['1-', '-5']`.  If a string contains an invalid token I would be satisfied with either ignoring the invalid token or the match failing completely.

Comment: Nice, I was thinking lookahead/behind as well. But what about the restriction that the separators contain only one comma? (I suppose that should be a question for the OP as well--what should be done in the case of multiple commas?)

Comment: @senderle, I approached the problem with `findall`, not with `split`; I don't think single comma 0/1 comma is not a restriction. Did I understand your comment correctly?

Comment: Yes, but I realized that it's more an ambiguity in the OP's question than a problem with your solution.

Comment: @senderle Yes I specified only zero/one coma between matches but for my purpose I am ok with treating multiple commas as a separator